# Make PHP array results show on page in different areas

Tags: php, arrays, hyperlink

I have created the following code that prepends an ezproxy code to a link if it is not there already. I have 6 links on my page, 4 with the prepend already and 2 without. Adding the prepend to the 2 links without it works fine, but how do I then call the results to replace the links that do not contain the prefix?

Here is my page: http://lis7440.slis.wayne.edu/eh3343/final/electronic.php

I need to replace the ACP Pier and BioMed links with the array results. The code I am using to prepend is:

```
<?php



 $array = array("http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessanesthesiology.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com",
 "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesssurgery.mhmedical.com", 
 "http://online.statref.com/Default.aspx?grpalias=MLC", "http://www.biomedcentral.com");



foreach($array as $value) {
    $pattern = '/^http?:\/\/proxy\.lib\.wayne\.edu\/login\?url=/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $value)) {

    echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
    else{
    $value = "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=".$value;

    }
    echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
    ?>
```

How do I replace those 2 links (ACP Pier and BioMed in the paragraph section) with the new prepended array results links?

Thanks for any advice.

The entire code is:

```
<!<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>

<head>
<title>Medical Library</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="library.css" />


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Electronic Resources</h1>
    </div>




    <div id="maincontent">

    <div class="divimg">
    <img src="medical.png" alt="Medical">
    </div>





<p><a href="http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessanesthesiology.mhmedical.com">AccessAnesthesiology (McGraw Hill)</a></p>

<p>In AccessAnesthesiology, physicians and residents can access a compendium of medical resources, including exclusive procedural videos, 
Custom Curriculum, and power search functionality, blended seamlessly with tables and charts designed for quick reference. Backed by an 
esteemed advisory board, AccessAnesthesiology offers multiple tools for resident education and certification/recertification in pain 
managements, critical care, and perioperative medicine.</p>

<p><a href="http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com">AccessMedicine</a></p>

<p>A repository of medical knowledge from internal medicine, cardiology, genetics, pharmacy, diagnosis and management, basic sciences, 
patient care, and more. Continuously expanding, all databases in the repository contain the latest editions of selected medical titles.</p>

<p><a href="http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com">AccessPharmacy (AccessPharmacy)</a></p>

<p>Users can search over 20 core curriculum textbooks, identify a core topic, or browse site by organ system. Case studies, 
care plans, self-assessments and NAPLEX review help students develop and track key skills providing critical feedback for students and teachers. 
Other features include information on clinical relevance and lab tests, comprehensive drug database, news & updates from Pharmacotherapy News 
Network (PNN) and Goodman & Gilmans Pharmacological Basis of Therapeutics.</p>

<p><a href="http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesssurgery.mhmedical.com">AccessSurgery (McGraw-Hill)</a></p>

<p>McGraw-Hill's AccessSurgery.com is an integrated online resource that provides medical students, surgical residents, and practicing 
surgeons with quick answers to surgical inquiries from trusted sources. Organized around the ACGME's (Accreditation Council for Graduate 
Medical Education) mandate for a Core Curriculum, AccessSurgery delivers content in context.</p>

<p><a href="http://online.statref.com/Default.aspx?grpalias=MLC">ACP Pier: The physician information and education resource (STATRef)</a></p>

<p>PIER is evidence-based clinical guidance presented electronically in a unique layered and telegraphic format. 
It is designed for rapid access to clinical information at the point of care. PIER includes recommendations based 
on all levels of medical evidence including RCTs, cohort and observational studies, case reports, and expert opinion.</p>

<p><a href="http://www.biomedcentral.com">BioMed Central (Biomed Central)</a></p>

<p>BioMed Central Ltd., an independent publisher in London, England, provides free access to biomedical research publications. 
These publications include biology and medicine journal articles, current reports, and meeting abstracts. BioMed Central offers
 information about current controlled trials, as well as topics in modern biology.</p>

 <?php



 $array = array("http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessanesthesiology.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com",
 "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesssurgery.mhmedical.com", 
 "http://online.statref.com/Default.aspx?grpalias=MLC", "http://www.biomedcentral.com");



foreach($array as $value) {
    $pattern = '/^http?:\/\/proxy\.lib\.wayne\.edu\/login\?url=/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $value)) {

    echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
    else{
    $value = "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=".$value;

    }
    echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
    ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok so why are you executing the PHP at the bottom? Why can't you just edit the links adding 'http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=' infront of them? I'm not sure the purpose of writing the PHP when the content is manually entered anyway

Are you not getting the links from a database?

Comment: Yeah, I know it makes no sense, but this is the assignment so that's the way I have to do it. I am linking to electronic databases available through a university and adding the eproxy to the links that do not have it. The theory is that this would be easier than going through and manually adding the proxy prepend if you had a lot of links on one page.

Comment: Ok so where is your code where you print out the title/link and corresponding paragraph from the database?

Comment: No code for that, just did it manually.

Comment: You can't edit HTML that is already on the page with PHP you need to use Javascript or actually get these details from the database and as you go through test the link. I can give you same code for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the second echo inside the IF

```
$array = array("http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessanesthesiology.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com","http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com", "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesssurgery.mhmedical.com", "http://online.statref.com/Default.aspx?grpalias=MLC", "http://www.biomedcentral.com");

foreach($array as $value) {
$pattern = '/^http?:\/\/proxy\.lib\.wayne\.edu\/login\?url=/';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $value)) {
        echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
    else{
        $value = "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=".$value;
        echo "<a href=$value>Database</a>";
    }
}
```

**Edit added PHP soluition with dummy database**

```
<?php

$resources = array();
// Add Resources to Array (fake DB)
array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessanesthesiology.mhmedical.com',
    'title' => 'AccessAnesthesiology (McGraw Hill)',
    'text' => 'In AccessAnesthesiology, physicians and residents can access a compendium of medical resources, including exclusive procedural videos, 
    Custom Curriculum, and power search functionality, blended seamlessly with tables and charts designed for quick reference. Backed by an 
    esteemed advisory board, AccessAnesthesiology offers multiple tools for resident education and certification/recertification in pain 
    managements, critical care, and perioperative medicine.'
));

array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accessmedicine.mhmedical.com',
    'title' => 'AccessMedicine',
    'text' => 'A repository of medical knowledge from internal medicine, cardiology, genetics, pharmacy, diagnosis and management, basic sciences, 
    patient care, and more. Continuously expanding, all databases in the repository contain the latest editions of selected medical titles.'
));

array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesspharmacy.mhmedical.com',
    'title' => 'AccessPharmacy (AccessPharmacy)',
    'text' => 'Users can search over 20 core curriculum textbooks, identify a core topic, or browse site by organ system. Case studies, 
    care plans, self-assessments and NAPLEX review help students develop and track key skills providing critical feedback for students and teachers. 
    Other features include information on clinical relevance and lab tests, comprehensive drug database, news & updates from Pharmacotherapy News 
    Network (PNN) and Goodman & Gilmans Pharmacological Basis of Therapeutics.'
));

array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=http://accesssurgery.mhmedical.com',
    'title' => 'AccessSurgery (McGraw-Hill)',
    'text' => "McGraw-Hill's AccessSurgery.com is an integrated online resource that provides medical students, surgical residents, and practicing 
    surgeons with quick answers to surgical inquiries from trusted sources. Organized around the ACGME's (Accreditation Council for Graduate 
    Medical Education) mandate for a Core Curriculum, AccessSurgery delivers content in context."
));

array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://online.statref.com/Default.aspx?grpalias=MLC',
    'title' => 'ACP Pier: The physician information and education resource (STATRef)',
    'text' => 'PIER is evidence-based clinical guidance presented electronically in a unique layered and telegraphic format. 
    It is designed for rapid access to clinical information at the point of care. PIER includes recommendations based 
    on all levels of medical evidence including RCTs, cohort and observational studies, case reports, and expert opinion.'
));

array_push($resources, array(
    'link' => 'http://www.biomedcentral.com',
    'title' => 'BioMed Central (Biomed Central)',
    'text' => 'BioMed Central Ltd., an independent publisher in London, England, provides free access to biomedical research publications. 
    These publications include biology and medicine journal articles, current reports, and meeting abstracts. BioMed Central offers
     information about current controlled trials, as well as topics in modern biology.'
));

?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>

<head>
<title>Medical Library</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="library.css" />


</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Electronic Resources</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="maincontent">

    <div class="divimg">
    <img src="medical.png" alt="Medical">
    </div>


<?php foreach ($resources as $resource) : ?>

    <?php 
    $pattern = '/^http?:\/\/proxy\.lib\.wayne\.edu\/login\?url=/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $resource['link'])) $resource['link'] = "http://proxy.lib.wayne.edu/login?url=" . $resource['link'];
    ?>

    <p><a href="<?php echo $resource['link']?>"><?php echo $resource['title'] ?></a></p>

    <p><?php echo $resource['text']; ?></p>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That gets me closer, but I still need to actually have the array result (which is a link) replace the current link on the page. For example, I do not need to replace any of the results from the first "if" statement because they already have the prefix I want, but the two links that the prefix is added to (ACP Pier: The physician information and education resource (STATRef) & BioMed Central (Biomed Central)) on the "else" statement need to actually be replaced by the array results where they appear on the page: http://lis7440.slis.wayne.edu/eh3343/final/electronic.php

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes it makes sense.. but how do you input the page to the function? Do you parse in the HTML? Maybe add the rest of the electronic.php code to your question so I can see